I have some questions regarding mat-icon-button, mat-icon and mat-menu
I wanted to do the following things with this icon:

Change the color of the icon while the menu is displayed
Make the menu a different color
Center the menu regarding the icon
Have the menu a little more separated from the icon

This is the html file:
<div class="icon-container">
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        <mat-icon class="login-icon">account_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before" class="menu">
        <button mat-menu-item class="menu-item">Login</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Sign Up</button>
    </mat-menu>
</div>

This is the css file:
.login-icon{
    color: #94a1b2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scale(2.6);
}

.icon-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-self: flex-end;
    margin-right: 4rem;
}

The following css code:
.menu-item{
    background-color: #94a1b2;
}

.menu{
    background-color: #94a1b2;
}

Has this result
Meanwhile this code:
.login-icon:active{
    color: #2cb67d;
}

Only changes the color of the icon if you click in a specific part of the icon. Also, I wanted to know if there was a way for the icon to retain the color while the menu is open.
